# Start a new random Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, random

how can I start a random activity after button click?
After the start Button must start the Activity 1, the Activity 2 or the Activity 3 in random mode..how can i do?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    start = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bstart);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //here must start a random activity..
        }
    });
```

Comment: Random random = new Random();  switch(random.nextInt(3)) { case 1: start activity 1 break; case 2: start activity 2 break; case 3: start activity 3 break; }

Comment: I've try with your code but don't function..

Comment: `code` Random random1 = new Random(); switch(random1.nextInt(2)) { case 1:  intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Livello2.class); break; 2:  intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 2_2.class);break; } 
start = (Button) findViewById (R.id.start); start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {Random random1 = new Random(); 
switch(random1.nextInt(2)) {case 1:  intent=new intent(getApplicationContext(), 2.class); break;case 2: intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 2_2.class);break;   }tv.setText(Integer.toString(i));intent.putExtra("",i);} `code`

Comment: how can this code doesn't work? of course you have to replace the text with a intent declaration

Comment: start only one intent!i don't know why!! this is my intent declaration: `code` Random random1 = new Random(); 
     switch(random1.nextInt(2)) { 
     case 1:  intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Livello2.class); 
     case 2:  intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Livello2_2.class); 
     } `code` something wrong here?

Comment: yes, you are mising the `break;` at the end of each `case`.

Comment: I've solved!! this is my code:   Random random1 = new Random(); 
  switch(random1.nextInt(3)) { 
  case 0:  intent2_1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Livello2_1.class); break;
  case 1:  intent2=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Livello2_2.class); break;
  case 2:  intent3=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Livello2_3.class); break;

  } and after it with intent button..THANKS!!